# nut client configuration issue

Tags: ubuntu, ups, nut

There are 2 UPS NUT servers running in my rack. 1 is running on TrueNAS SCALE and another is running on Synology DS918+. And there is a NUT client running on a ubuntu server.

The NUT client keeps complaining:

```
Broadcast message from nut@nuc13 (somewhere) (Sat Jan 27 16:16:52 2024):       
                                                                               
UPS APC_ES850_G2@10.27.0.40 is unavailable                                     
                                                                               
                                                                               
Broadcast message from nut@nuc13 (somewhere) (Sat Jan 27 16:16:52 2024):       
                                                                               
UPS APC_ES850_G2_new@10.27.0.61 is unavailable
```

**Could someone help me fix it?**

Here is the content of my upsmon.conf after comments are removed:

```
MONITOR APC_ES850_G2@10.27.0.40 1 [username] [password] secondary
MONITOR APC_ES850_G2_new@10.27.0.61 0 [username] [password] secondary

MINSUPPLIES 1

SHUTDOWNCMD "/sbin/shutdown -h +0"

POLLFREQ 5

POLLFREQALERT 5

HOSTSYNC 15

DEADTIME 15

POWERDOWNFLAG /etc/killpower

RBWARNTIME 43200

NOCOMMWARNTIME 300

FINALDELAY 5
```

With telnet, it seems to work. Here is an example connecting to DS918+ from the ubuntu server (It is IP based authentication. Login is not required):

```
$ telnet 10.27.0.40 3493
Trying 10.27.0.40...
Connected to 10.27.0.40.
Escape character is '^]'.
LIST UPS
BEGIN LIST UPS
UPS ups "Description unavailable"
END LIST UPS
LIST VAR ups
BEGIN LIST VAR ups
VAR ups battery.charge "100"
VAR ups battery.charge.low "10"
VAR ups battery.charge.warning "50"
VAR ups battery.date "2001/09/25"
VAR ups battery.mfr.date "2020/10/04"
VAR ups battery.runtime "1316"
VAR ups battery.runtime.low "120"
VAR ups battery.type "PbAc"
VAR ups battery.voltage "13.6"
VAR ups battery.voltage.nominal "12.0"
VAR ups device.mfr "American Power Conversion"
VAR ups device.model "Back-UPS ES 850G2"
VAR ups device.serial "5B2040T68465  "
VAR ups device.type "ups"
VAR ups driver.name "usbhid-ups"
VAR ups driver.parameter.pollfreq "30"
VAR ups driver.parameter.pollinterval "5"
VAR ups driver.parameter.port "auto"
VAR ups driver.parameter.synchronous "no"
VAR ups driver.version "DSM7-2-60108-221130"
VAR ups driver.version.data "APC HID 0.96"
VAR ups driver.version.internal "0.41"
VAR ups input.sensitivity "medium"
VAR ups input.transfer.high "266"
VAR ups input.transfer.low "180"
VAR ups input.voltage "241.0"
VAR ups input.voltage.nominal "230"
VAR ups ups.beeper.status "enabled"
VAR ups ups.delay.shutdown "20"
VAR ups ups.firmware "938.a2 .I"
VAR ups ups.firmware.aux "a"
VAR ups ups.load "22"
VAR ups ups.mfr "American Power Conversion"
VAR ups ups.mfr.date "2020/10/04"
VAR ups ups.model "Back-UPS ES 850G2"
VAR ups ups.productid "0002"
VAR ups ups.realpower.nominal "520"
VAR ups ups.serial "5B2040T68465  "
VAR ups ups.status "OL"
VAR ups ups.test.result "No test initiated"
VAR ups ups.timer.reboot "0"
VAR ups ups.timer.shutdown "-1"
VAR ups ups.vendorid "051d"
END LIST VAR ups
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

and there is no problem connecting to the TrueNAS from ubuntu either:

```
$ telnet 10.27.0.61 3493
Trying 10.27.0.61...
Connected to 10.27.0.61.
Escape character is '^]'.
USERNAME [username]
OK
PASSWORD [password]
OK
LIST UPS
BEGIN LIST UPS
UPS APC_ES850_G2-new "APC Back-UPS ES850 G2 new"
END LIST UPS
LIST VAR APC_ES850_G2-new
BEGIN LIST VAR APC_ES850_G2-new
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.charge "100"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.charge.low "10"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.charge.warning "50"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.date "2001/09/25"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.mfr.date "2023/06/19"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.runtime "1228"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.runtime.low "120"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.type "PbAc"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.voltage "13.5"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new battery.voltage.nominal "12.0"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new device.mfr "American Power Conversion"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new device.model "Back-UPS ES 850G2"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new device.serial "5B2325T40076  "
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new device.type "ups"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.name "usbhid-ups"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.parameter.pollfreq "30"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.parameter.pollinterval "2"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.parameter.port "auto"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.parameter.synchronous "auto"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.version "2.8.0"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.version.data "APC HID 0.98"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.version.internal "0.47"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new driver.version.usb "libusb-1.0.26 (API: 0x1000109)"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new input.sensitivity "medium"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new input.transfer.high "266"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new input.transfer.low "180"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new input.voltage "242.0"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new input.voltage.nominal "230"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.beeper.status "enabled"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.delay.shutdown "20"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.firmware "938.a2 .I USB "
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.load "28"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.mfr "American Power Conversion"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.mfr.date "2023/06/19"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.model "Back-UPS ES 850G2"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.productid "0002"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.realpower.nominal "520"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.serial "5B2325T40076  "
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.status "OL"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.test.result "No test initiated"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.timer.reboot "0"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.timer.shutdown "-1"
VAR APC_ES850_G2-new ups.vendorid "051d"
END LIST VAR APC_ES850_G2-new
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me.

I have solved the issue. upsmon.conf requires the exact name of the ups entity listed from the nut server, i.e. the first lines of the upsmon.conf should be

```
MONITOR ups@10.27.0.40 1 [username] [password] secondary
MONITOR APC_ES850_G2-new@10.27.0.61 0 [username] [password] secondary
```